# Notification Service for browser extensions

Tags: firefox, azure, opera, azure-notificationhub

I want to understand if **Azure Notification Hub** can be used to send notifications to my browser extensions. I know it support **GCM**, **APNS**, **ADM**, which is compatible with

1. GCM => Chrome Extension.
2. APNS => Safari Extension.

But what about Firefox and Opera?
I can't find any PNS on Azure Notification Hub that is compatible with these two browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox and Opera are not currently supported. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-faq/ for web notifications, and here are the [chrome](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-chrome-get-started/) and [safari](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/tree/master/PushToSafari) tutorials/samples.